# Get paid to like on facebook legal or illegal? (.. and Google+ ?)

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, google-plus

Just checking it for my GPT site,
Is it LEGAL to get pay my users for liking my page on Facebook?
And the same for google+ (Pay my users for pushing the google+ button)?

I searched like whole Facebook / Google to find the guidelines and check this, but i haven't found something.

Thnx!

Comment: Does the number of likes mean so much then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **looks** like you can as long as the site/application is your own.

From: http://developers.facebook.com/policy/#integration

> c. You must not incentivize users to Like any Page other than your own site or application, and any incentive you provide must be available to new and existing users who Like your Page.

As for legal, I honestly can't think of a single law that would be violated if you gave someone money to perform the action of liking your page.